# How to get data of a previous step in django FormWizard

Tags: python, django, formwizard

Please recommend me the way how to get data, received in the first step of wizard, and use it in the form of second step:

forms.py

```
# First step form
class W1_ParamForm(forms.Form):
    cities = forms.ModelChoiceField( label = 'City', 
        queryset=City.objects.all().order_by('name') )

# Second step form
class W1_SelectForm(forms.Form):
    oEstates = MyModelMultipleChoiceField( 
        queryset = RealEstate.objects.
            filter(city_id__exact = ...).
            order_by('priceM'),
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required = False)
```

Herein ... - parameter, containing city id, selected in a first form W1_ParamForm. The problem - how to get it in the second form!

views.py

```
class W1_Estim(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "w1_estim.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]       
        return render_to_response('w1_done.html', {'form_data': form_data})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 ...
# Wizard start
   url(r'^doestim$', W1_Estim.as_view([W1_ParamForm,W1_SelectForm]), name='doestim'),
 ...
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I got it! In order to recieve data from previous step, one must

A) Implement get_form_initial(self, step) for view class W1_Estim

```
def get_form_initial(self, step):
   if step == '1': 
      # on SECOND step get data of first step
      step0data = self.storage.get_step_data('0')
      if step0data:
         cities = step0data.get('cities', '')
         return self.initial_dict.get(step, {'cities': cities})
   return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
```

B) Implement constructor for form class W1_SelectForm

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   c = kwargs['initial']['cities']
   self.oEstates = ModelMultipleChoiceField( 
      queryset = RealEstate.objects.
      filter(city_id = c).
      order_by('priceM'),
      widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
      required = False)
   # NEED TO INCLUDE field oEstates into "declared_fields"!!!
   self.declared_fields['oEstates']=self.oEstates
   # superclass constructor ought to be called only AFTER 
   # including new field of class into "declared_fields" !!!
   super(W1_SelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thats all!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_cleaned_data_for_step()`](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_cleaned_data_for_step) method of the wizard view.

```
class W1_Estim(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "w1_estim.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        ...
        data_for_step1 = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('1')
        #do something with data_for_step1
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion is not applicable, becouse "done" is too late - its necessary to get the data of step one at the stage, when second form does not appear still - in order to make queryset, depending on data of step one.

Comment: @user3611898, you can call the same function from wherever you want, after completing the particular step.

Comment: I understand it, but how can I receive that data in constructor of W1_SelectForm? I'll be very grateful if you'll explain it to me!

Comment: May be I think in a wrong way and it's another variant to do what I need? For example, move queryset construction and execution in another place, in some method of W1_SelectForm? Django (and Python itself) absolutely new for me...

Comment: Thanks, Rohan, you inspired me and I found the solution, based on your proposal! I can not vote - don't have enough reputation, sorry...